# Excel - List of key values created from external files in power query, trouble with editing mapped values

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot, datamodel

I am attempting to create a standardized list of names for a long list of free typed values in a list of csv's pulled from Jira.

What I have tried so far has been to use Get Data -> From File -> From Folder
And then narrow it down to just the column I need and then remove all duplicate rows.

After loading that, I have tried adding a column that's just an empty string.  I have done this both in power query and in the data model with the same effect.  I want to have the second column so the user can map the values in the key column on a worksheet. This table will be used as a map for pivot tables to standardize names.  Attempting to update the value in a worksheet and then refreshing to see that change in the data model just reverts the value back to an empty string.

Obviously i'm going about this the wrong way.  The goal is to be able to maintain this key, value map over the months as new keys are added to it and just have to map those new entries rather than having to do a lot of work with comparing every time to see whats new.  Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do and still maintain it being expandable over the months without having to redo the entire workbook?

Comment: You have not explained why are you adding a column that is empty.  Are you planning to input manual data that you want to preserve for the next go-around? If so see https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Comment: You are right, edited 3rd paragraph, apologies

Comment: As expected.  Read https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Comment: That appears to be the solution I was looking for.  Thank you so much!